# Php not echoing Mysqli db errors

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Is there something I need to set in php to make it display mysqli prepared statement errors?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("my query string...");

if ( false===$stmt ) {
  echo $db->error;
}
```

It echoes nothing.

Comment: make sure error reporting of php is turned on as well

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to make `$db->error` work.

Comment: Are you sure the prepared statement has an error? Try doing `echo "Error: " . $db->error;` to be sure you're in the `if`.

Comment: Yes there is an error, I intentionally put a non existent table in the query string. To add I am running the code inside a function with $stmt as an input variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make $db global in the function. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Do you sure that there are errors? Just add to  output  any string. For example

```
if ( false===$stmt ) {
  echo "Prepare error:" . $db->error;
}
```

Comment: I needed to make $db global in the function. It works now!

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

something like that.
source :  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php